# How do I vertically align something inside a span tag?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the "x" to be vertically-aligned in the middle of the span?

```
.foo {
    height: 50px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<span class="foo">
   x
</span>
```

Answer (score 259):

Use `line-height:50px;` instead of height. That should do the trick ;)

Comment: Excelent! It works to any type of tag. In my case, worked to <img>.

Comment: The problem is when the text wraps. With two lines this span will be rendered with 100px height.

Comment: if your text wraps try my answer @NorbertoYoan

Comment: ditto for @Sumit (duplicated because of [issue with SO's comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45273/allow-more-than-one-name-notification-per-comment))

Comment: This shouldn't be the top voted answer, has the solution might give some other undesired results depending on the content.

Answer (score 124):

Be aware that the `line-height` approach fails if you have a long sentence in the `span` which breaks the line because there's not enough space. In this case, you would have two lines with a gap with the height of the N pixels specified in the property.

I stuck into it when I wanted to show an image with vertically centered text on its right side which works in a responsive web application. As a base I use the approach suggested by Eric Nickus and Felipe Tadeo.

If you want to achieve:

[image: desktop]

and this:

[image: mobile]

```css
.container {
    background: url( "https://i.imgur.com/tAlPtC4.jpg" ) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 40px 40px; /* image's size */
    height: 40px; /* image's height */
    padding-left: 50px; /* image's width plus 10 px (margin between text and image) */
}

.container span {
    height: 40px; /* image's height */
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
    <span>This is a centered sentence next to an image</span>
</span>
```

Comment: what is a dyanmic height

Answer (score 47):

This is the simplest way to do it if you need multiple lines. Wrap you `span`'d text in another `span` and specify its height with `line-height`. The trick to multiple lines is resetting the inner `span`'s `line-height`.

```html
<span class="textvalignmiddle"><span>YOUR TEXT HERE</span></span>
```

```css
.textvalignmiddle {
    line-height: /*set height*/;
}

.textvalignmiddle > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1em; /*set line height back to normal*/
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QAwpm/1/)

Of course the outer `span` could be a `div` or whathaveyou

Comment: `span`s, like any other inline element, [can contain any HTML inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545884/can-span-tags-have-any-type-of-tags-inside-them#5545914). Regardless, I wrote that `textvalignmiddle` can be a `div` if so necessary (and you can set it to `display:inline;` if you're so averse to using `spans`)

Comment: I mean't they shouldn't have. They are for containing text. Else use a div.

Comment: `span` is the [*generic* inline container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) for html and doesnt so much as hint at being text only; ` It can be used to group **elements** for styling purposes...`. I suggest reading the spec before pushing your personal coding standards on others stating them as fact

Comment: either way, this line of conversation isnt constructive in a technical sense to the question and isnt what comments in SO are for

Comment: Works for me too. Used a different element than span.

Comment: Doesn't work for me when using the following doctype tag:              <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: If you're actually using transitional elements, why bother with `doctype`s in the first place, IMO. Any reason why you need to declare your document transitional?

Answer (score 46):

The flexbox way:

```
.foo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: since `.foo` is a span `display: flex-inline` would fit better

Comment: Did you mean "inline-flex"?

Answer (score 5):

I needed this for links, so I wrapped the span with an a-tag and a div, then centered the span tag itself

HTML

```
<div>
    <a class="tester" href="#">
        <span>Home</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tester{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9em;
    height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}
.tester>span{
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I hate messing with CSS, I was spending all day trying to vertically center an element when I came across your answer here.  You're a life saver!

Answer (score 5):

**CSS vertical center image and text**

I have Create one demo for vertical image center and text also i have test on firefox ,chrome,safari, internet explorer 9 and 8 too.

It is very short and easy css and html, Please check below code and you can find output on screenshort.

**HTML**

```
<div class="frame">
    <img src="capabilities_icon1.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .frame {
        height: 160px;      
        width: 160px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: center; margin: 1em 0;
    }

    .frame::before {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        content:"";
    }

    img {
        background: #3A6F9A;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

**Output**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFquE.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

this works for me (Keltex said the same)

```
.foo {
height: 50px;
...
}
.foo span{
vertical-align: middle; 
}

<span class="foo"> <span>middle!</span></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just giving an alternative, in case you encapsulate your element in a flexible container (e.g.: display: flex):

```
align-self: center;
```

[More info](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-self.asp)

Answer (score 1):

The vertical-align css attribute doesn't do what you expect unfortunately. [This article](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html) explains 2 ways to vertically align an element using css.

Answer (score 1):

Set padding-top to be an appropriate value to push the x down, then subtract the value you have for padding-top from the height.