# Can <span> tags have any type of tags inside them?

Tags: html, xhtml

Are tags such as `<div>`, `<form>`, `<pre>` etc.. allowed inside a `<span>`?

Comment: Seems to be a dead link.

Comment: @aetheria: [here u go](http://imgur.com/pOC2UJ1) (really cool graphic, I downloaded to my computer :P)

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for uploading that.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `span` element is an *inline* element, which should contain only other *inline* elements and no *block* elements.

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3):

> Generally, block-level elements may
>   contain inline elements and other
>   block-level elements. Generally,
>   inline elements may contain only data
>   and other inline elements. Inherent in
>   this structural distinction is the
>   idea that block elements create
>   "larger" structures than inline
>   elements.

The generic block-level grouping element is the `div`. The generic inline-level grouping element is the `span`.

Again, from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4):

> The DIV and SPAN elements, in
>   conjunction with the id and class
>   attributes, offer a generic mechanism
>   for adding structure to documents.
>   These elements define content to be
>   inline (SPAN) or block-level (DIV) but
>   impose no other presentational idioms
>   on the content.

Comment: Note that the keyword here is `should`.  If you put a DIV or any other block element into a SPAN, nothing bad is going to happen unless you really care about validating against spec.

Comment: @cwolves But why would you want to place a block-level element inside an inline-level element anyway? That would just be a bad idea.

Comment: Although it will not validate, you can make an inline element behave like a block-level element by using a proper CSS rule; like span{display:block}

Comment: @Šime Vidas You wouldn't in general, but playing devil's advocate, if you don't care about validation, and if you set `display: block` on the span, it just becomes another div effectively, and you could use it to filter by :)

Comment: @cwolves Yes, that's true. If you make the SPAN block-level, you'll effectively have another DIV. However, I don't recommend such a practice.

Comment: @Adám No license :). It’s outdated, though. HTML5 allows more liberal nesting.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [HTML Living Standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/), the content model for SPAN elements is "Phrasing content".

Read about the SPAN element [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element).

Read about phrasing content [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/content-models.html#phrasing-content). This second link contains a full list of all the elements that can be put inside a SPAN element.

Comment: Here's the w3c spec for `span`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element and `phrasing content`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#phrasing-content

Comment: @Sapph I like the [HTML Living Standard spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) more - it's more up to date and closer to the "source".

Comment: Vidas: At least in this case we have the two working groups in agreement :)

Comment: This explains why my HTML compiler doesn't accept `<span><p></p></span>` as a valid HTML and considers it as if it was `<span></span><p></p>` instead