# Can you have a <span> within a <span>?

Tags: html, css

Here is the story: I'm using SWFObject to insert a Flash object into my page. The embedding eats my `span`. So, I lose all my CSS for it. I was thinking of moving all of the CSS to the parent so I don't lose my CSS styles when the Flash appears.

I have tried using a `span` within a `span`, but I don't think it's working. Is there a reason for this? I don't understand why you could have `div` within a `div` but not a `span` within a `span`.

Does it have to do with `spans` being inline?

Comment: What do you mean by: "embedding eats my span". Also, please provide a [reduced test case](http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/) on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) or [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: A span isn't any different than a div except that by default the properties of each tend to be defined a certain way. However, they're both just elements. You could view a span as a block level element if you chose to do so. I think you're using the embed method incorrectly. I believe swfObject asks you to define an element for it to replace the contents of. Their example here: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation shows them replacing an object. Maybe you should do the same.

Comment: Wait, then how could you add text after the span tag? If you insert a span inside a span, then changing the text of the outside span would put it before the inner span. Is there a way to make that distinction?

Answer (score 435, accepted):

[HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) states that:

> Inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements

Span is an inline element, therefore having span inside span is valid.
There's a related question: [Can <span> tags have any type of tags inside them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545884/can-span-tags-have-any-type-of-tags-inside-them) which makes it completely clear.

[HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (including the most current draft of [HTML 5.3](https://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-span-element) dated November 16, 2017) changes terminology, but it's still perfectly valid to place span inside another span.

Answer (score 209):

Yes. You can have a `span` within a `span`. Your problem stems from something else.