# IntelliJ is not formatting HTML

Tags: html, intellij-idea

Have been using IntelliJ for years, and been happy and hope this is a fluke.
IntelliJ is not formatting HTML code when I do Ctrl-Alt-L. The dialog pops, and it pretends to format, but no code is actually moved. I switched extension of the file from HTML to XML, and formatting worked as expected. Actually I noticed this in Freemarker templates, but then experimented with pure HTML with the same results.
My version is 13.0.2

Answer (score 34):

Had the same problem, the statements under the  tag were not indented by default. Reformatting and auto-indentation worked after I changed the following:

Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> HTML -> Other (tab) -> Do not indent children of: -> remove "body" from the list.

Maybe it is the same for you or something related at this section. Hope it works for you aswell.

Comment: It was indeed the problem on WebStorm 2022.2.4

Answer (score 5):

Settings > Editor > Code Style > HTML.
Check your "tabs and indents", but most important, "other".

For example, the default "insert new lines before" value is "body,div,p,form,h1,h2,h3"

When I export my code style as .xml, (Settings > Editor > Code Style > Html > Manage button), I get a file default.xml with the following contents:

```
<code_scheme name="Default" />
```

You could try creating a "default.xml" file with this content, and using "import scheme". The fact that it's empty points out that all settings are IntelliJ default (as far as I know).

Also, make sure your extension is .html, as this is what intelliJ uses to detect languages. Make sure you format the whole file (in case it'd be formatting an empty selection, or it could be trying to format VCS changed text while there is none.

You could also try checking Settings > Editor > File types > Html:
This list should contain all extensions for which HTML syntax check and formatting is used. (see also [How can I open a file and see the HTML highlights in Intellij IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723824/how-can-i-open-a-file-and-see-the-html-highlights-in-intellij-idea?rq=1) )

I use IntelliJ 2016.1, but this part shouldn't be any different from IntelliJ 13

Answer (score 2):

Note that invalid HTML will not be reformatted. So if your badly outlined HTML is actually invalid as well, you can reformat all you like, but the lines that are not valid will not change.

This can be confusing at times, but once you know it it makes for good eye-catchers hinting at invalid code.

Common example, misuse of block elements:

```
<span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>1</span>
</span>
```

Comment: @skwisgaar Don't you see it? In browser's eyes, the `span` that opens in line 1 is closed by line 2. That is `<span><span>1</span>`...

Comment: @RomeoSierra I see only nested `span` elements which is fine (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118042/is-using-nested-spans-in-html-5-valid). If what you're saying were true then the whole internet would stop working because of the nested `div`s :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089953/can-you-have-a-span-within-a-span This is why I said **In browser's eyes**. `div`, in contrast with `span` is a **block element**.

Comment: I think the IntelliJ formatter thinks the outer span should be inline and not contain other block elements. I guess you're right that it is theoretically allowed by the spec, but that doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if you are using any Code Style plugins and try turning them off - looks like they take precedence over and may give unexpected results. At least for me, it was the solution.

In the *Settings/Preferences* dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), click *Plugins*.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Editor > Code Style > HTML > Other > delete everything from “Do not indent children of:”

Answer (score 0):

Right ok, best bet seems like something in the reformatting options has borked somehow, I'm currently using WebStorm and that round about has the same settings U.I.

In Preferences -> Editor -> Formatting -> "Show 'Reformat Code' Dialog. Give that a tick and that on code reformat it will pop a dialog and you can revise your reformat options there if any options are borked or not.

Comment: I use Intellij 13, and the reformat dialog does pop up. However it has no important options.

Comment: Right there's one possibility out the way, in Preferences there should be Code Style - This is what the code formatter refers to when formatting code, I would find your HTML code style and see if that is populated correctly, if even there at all. Additionally IntelliJ is a JAVA IDE so I'm not surprised there are problems.

Comment: @Raptus IntelliJ is the flagship product of the company, and it combines all features of PHPStorm and their other IDE's into the one program.  I don't know why they advertise it as a Java IDE.