# How can I open a file and see the HTML highlights in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: html, intellij-idea

I have some non-html files like "**.gohtml", but I don't know how to open it as a html file and see the highligts in Intellij IDEA.How can I do this.?

Comment: Right click, open with, ...?

Comment: there is no such option.: (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out by doing this three steps:

- Go to **Editor>File Types**
- Find the file Type **HTML** In **Recognized File Types**
- Enter the new wildcard(CLICK THE **PLUS BUTTON**) you want In **Registered Patterns**

Comment: Could you add some information about "the new wildcard" please

Comment: @bish `*.gohtml`, matching the example from the question.