# Align firstname and lastname on seperate lines in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an example navbar that I wish to modify for my own here. Currently the user's fullname is positioned on the same line like so:
[image: current fullname displayed like this]

How do I change the fullname position so they are displayed and aligned like this:
[image]

I createed an un-ordered list, but I think that is semantically incorrect and we can't put a `ul` inside a link anyway. It also wasn't working in IE either, so I am back to square one.

Any ideas would be helpful.

```css
body {
 padding-top: 102px;
 background-color: #4d4d4d;
 font-family: 'Lato', verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #010101;
}
.container {
 width: 1530px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header {
 min-height: 80px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-header button.hamburger-icon {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
 color: #010101;
 padding-top: 5px;
}
/* searchbox */
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.search .input-group {
 padding-top: 15px;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.search .input-group input.form-control {
 padding: 0 10px 0 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #010101;
 border-radius: 0;
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 100;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.search .input-group input.form-control:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.search .input-group-btn button {
 padding: 2px;
 border: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.search .input-group-btn button:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #ff5500;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.search .input-group-btn .glyphicon-search {
 font-size: 22px;
}
/* bell notification and dropdown */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a.inbox,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a.inbox:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a.inbox:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 padding-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.nav > li.dropdown.bell > a:hover,
.nav > li.dropdown.bell > a:focus {
 color: #ff5500;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.bell li a:hover {
 color: #ff5500;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.bell .badge-count {
 background: #ff5500;
 margin-top: -24px;
 margin-left: -20px;
 height: 1.7em;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell {
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell li a {
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 white-space: normal !important;
 width: 350px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell li a span.info {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell li.divider {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 20px;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell .label {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #aaa;
 font-weight: 100;
}
/* bell notification and dropdown caret */
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: -10px;
 right: 9%;
 display: inline-block;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 content: '';
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: -9px;
 right: 9%;
 display: inline-block;
 border-right: 9px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 9px solid #f8f8f8;
 border-left: 9px solid transparent;
 content: '';
}
/* create profile button */
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.create-profile a.create-profile-btn {
 width: 200px;
 padding: 12px;
 margin-top: 18px;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.create-profile a.btn-default {
 background-color: #ff5500;
 border-color: #ff5500;
 color: #fff;
}
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.create-profile a.btn-default:hover,
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.create-profile a.btn-default:focus,
.navbar-nav > .dropdown.create-profile a.btn-default:active {
 color: #fff;
 border-color: 0;
 /*set the color you want here*/
}
/* user login and dropdown */
.navbar-nav > .user-logged-in span.firstname {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #010101;
}
.navbar-nav > .user-logged-in span.surname {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #010101;
}
.navbar-nav > .user-logged-in .dropdown-menu.access-list {
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 0;
 border: 0;
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.navbar-nav > .user-logged-in .dropdown-menu.access-list li a {
 margin: 5px 0px;
 color: #010101;
}
.navbar-nav > .user-logged-in .dropdown-menu.access-list li a:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #ff5500;
}
.navbar-nav > .user-logged-in .dropdown-menu.access-list li.divider {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 20px;
}
.fullname {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.drop-arr {
 float: right;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
span.avatar {
 padding-right: 90px;
}
/* Large desktop */
@media (max-width: 1590px) {
 .container {
   width: auto;
 }
}
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (max-width: 979px) {}
/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .container {
   width: auto;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
   font-size: 40px;
 }
 /* bell notification and dropdown */
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a.inbox,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a.inbox:focus,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a.inbox:hover {
   width: 100% !important;
   background-color: #e7e7e7;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
 .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell li a {
   width: 100%;
 }
 .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell:before,
 .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell:after {
   display: none;
 }
 .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu.bell li a {
   text-align: left;
 }
 .navbar-nav > .dropdown.bell,
 .navbar-nav > .user-logged-in {
   text-align: center;
 }
 /* searchbox */
 .navbar-nav > .dropdown.search {
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 .navbar-nav > .dropdown.search .input-group {
   padding-top: 0;
 }
}
/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
   font-size: 30px;
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-md" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hamburger-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <h1>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" height="30" width="180"></a>
   </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <!-- search bar -->
          <li class="dropdown search">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search name or keyword" name="q">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/search-128.png" height="30" width="30" class=" avatar-img img-square">
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </li>

          <!-- notification bell -->
          <li class="dropdown bell">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle inbox" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-bell-outline-128.png" height="45" width="45" class=" avatar-img img-square">
              <span class="badge badge-count">1</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu bell" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-default">4:00 AM</span><span class="info">Favourites Snippet</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">4:30 AM</span><span class="info">Email marketing</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span class="label label-warning">5:00 AM</span>
       <span class="info">
        Subscriber focused email design
        Extra sample line
        Extra sample line
        Extra sample line
       </span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="text-center">View All</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <!-- create profile button -->
          <!-- <li class="dropdown create-profile">
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg create-profile-btn" href="#" role="button">Create a profile</a>
    </li> -->

          <!-- user login information -->
          <li class="dropdown user-logged-in">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle username" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="avatar"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-128.png" height="50" width="50" ></span>
              <span class="drop-arr"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png" height="20" width="20" ></span>
              <span class="fullname">
       <span class="firstname">Jacky</span>
              <br><span class="surname">Smith</span>
              </span>

            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu access-list" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">ssdfsdf</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">fsfsdfs</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">sfsfsf</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">fsdfsdsd</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">dlfjsdlfjs</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>dfsjfhskfs</p>


      <!-- <div class="chevron right">
     <a href="#"></a>
   </div>

   <div style="height: 1em;">
   </div> -->




    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.navbar-login {
  width: 305px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar-login-session {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
.icon-size {
  font-size: 87px;
}
.glyphicon-user {
    position: absolute !important;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    left: 5px;
    top: 50% !important;
}
.glyphicon-chevron-down {
    position: absolute !important;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    right: 5px;
    top: 50% !important;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 35px;
    padding-left: 35px;
 }

 .name {
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a target="_blank" href="#" class="navbar-brand">My sApp.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/nav-account-manager" target="_blank">Inspirado en este ejemplo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DropDown
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-right username" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            <span class="name">Nombre</span>
            <strong class="name">lastname</strong>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <div class="navbar-login">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <p class="text-center">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-size"></span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <p class="text-left"><strong>Nombre Apellido</strong>
                    </p>
                    <p class="text-left small">correoElectronico@email.com</p>
                    <p class="text-left">
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm">Actualizar Datos</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <div class="navbar-login navbar-login-session">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Muhammed Usman, the html and css is different, I updated it now, so can you check it see how I can fix this in IE??

Comment: @Krystyna add `span.avatar {flaot: left;}`

Comment: @Muhammed that doesnt really work, the dropdown is affected and the background hover is messed up

Comment: @Krystyna `.navbar-nav > li > a.dropdown-toggle {overflow: hidden;}` will fix background issue

Comment: @Muhammed, I think that worked! the `overflow: hidden` works even without the `float: left`, so I think thats good, what do you think?

Comment: @Krystyna yes you should use only overflow: hidden.  I think it was layout issue with IE. `overflow: hidden` sets layout and your issue gets solved.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `</br>` would do:

```
<span>First Name </br> <strong>Last Name<strong> </span>
```

Comment: How do I fix this for IE, the break pushed it down

Comment: the html and css is different, can you check out the snippet again?

Comment: `</br>` is invalid syntax. You could either do `<br>` or `<br />`.

Comment: @Krystyna I see what you mean. Maybe  `.navbar-nav > li > a.dropdown-toggle`  should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing a little bit the structure of this :

```
    <span class="nombre">
      <span>Nombre</span>
      <span><strong>lastname</strong></span>
    </span>
```

And the relevant CSS :

```
.username .nombre {width: 75px; display: inline-block; text-align: right; margin-right: 10px;}
.glyphicon { vertical-align: top; padding-top: 15px; }
.glyphicon:first-child { padding-top: 10px}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7r2g36f/4/)

Comment: can you put a div in a link??

Comment: You're right, it was semanticly incorrect. I changed it to a `span ` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089953/can-you-have-span-within-span

Comment: this is allwell and good, but what if the user has a long firstname/lastname?? it shouldnt have a width like that, it should just do the width automatically

Comment: Ok, in that case, you can remove the width and add a `<br/>` in the `span` : https://jsfiddle.net/x7r2g36f/5/

Comment: I updated the html and css, have a look at it now...the name doesnt work properly in IE...

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="float:right">Nombre</span>
<p class="clear">
        <span style="float:right"><strong>lastname</strong></span>
```

in css add

```
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
```

and use it in situations like this :)

you could also use something like this

```
<span style="float:right">Nombre</span>
    <br/>
    <span style="float:right"><strong>lastname</strong></span>
```

but i think that will separate them too much