# jsoup span in span return as single bject

Tags: jsoup

I'm trying to dig some data from this html,
the html has span inside another span ([Seems like valid html according to other stack over flow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089953/can-you-have-span-within-span))

so the expression

```
td  > p > span
```

return 2 elements (second element has both span's in it)
is there a way around this?

in this example, the value is I'm interested in is **03/26/17**

```
<td width="414" style="width:310.25pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid #AEAAAA 1.0pt;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:.3in">
    <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal">
&nbsp;

        <span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">03/</span>
        <span style="font-size:8.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif">26<span style="color:black">/17</span>
        </span>
        <o:p/>
    </p>
</td>
```

Code:

```
protected String getSimpleValue(org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc,String selector) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

    try {           
        Elements result = doc.select(selector);

        for (Element element : result) {
            buff.append(element.ownText()+" ");
            }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
return buff.toString();
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect and what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try below code. that will give the exactly result what you want.

```
 Element ele= document.select("p[class=MsoNormal]").get(0);
 String strdate = ele.text().replaceAll(" ", "");
 System.out.println(strdate);
```

**Explanation:** U can directly create the element of `p`, `class="MsoNormal"` and use `.text()` for getting the text. as there some space is coming so can use `.replaceAll(" ", "")` for that.
Hope this will help you.

**Your result :** `03/26/17`

Answer (score 1):

The selector for "03/" is `.MsoNormal > span:nth-child(1)` and the selector for "26/17" is `.MsoNormal > span:nth-child(2)`.
You can see it [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~AF8vKSe-IBxqTb8XdICGSi4xt2Y).