# Html h1 tag inside span tag

Tags: html

I have a task where I need to add some `h1` tags on several pages inside a web application. The texts already exists but wrapped inside other tags which I need to convert to h1 tags. While I do this I need to keep the same design on the page, so design wise nothing should change. We need h1 tags for google bot.

Let me show you below an example. Currently I have on a page this:

```html
<span class="container">
   <span class="icon"></span>
   <span class="page-title">
      <span class="title">Title</span>
   </span>
</span>
```

And I need to insert `h1` there. I've read on the internet that it is not a good idea to add a `h1` inside a `span` because my first idea was to replace the `span.title` with `h1` and style that `h1` in order to look like that `span`.

The whole block is basically an angular component which is used just for this heading section (you can see it also contains an icon before the text).

For this particular situation we have to deal with `spans`, but in other cases there are `divs` or other elements.

What is the best way to handle this situation ?

Comment: Just put an H1 in there. It's not great semantically but it should work

Comment: Since HTML5 there are not strict rules about tags.
Actually, you can use your own tags and the site will not break

Comment: @Omiod — HTML 5 has very clear rules about what tags are allowed where.

Comment: H1 elements may not appear inside span elements. Write semantic markup.

Comment: Basically I need to add it there and set it as inline + some font decrease to look the same as before. However it is ok to do so ? What options there are ? What problems can I have if I do this? Can google bot have an issue with this ?

Comment: If .container only has the icon and title, I would just change that span to the h1

Comment: Supporting documentation for @Quentin's points above: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span (see "Permitted content" and "Permitted parents")

Comment: To be short. What are the consequences of using h1 instead of that span ?

Comment: You ask: 'What are the consequences of using h1 instead of that span' - one consequence is that the code will fail W3C validation with: Error: Element h1 not allowed as child of element span in this context. Whether you care is another matter, not for me to judge, but it might not look good to anyone picking up your code, and it does seem strange having something called 'container' and a couple of things with 'title' as spans.

Answer (score 2):

`<span>`s **can't** contain `<h1>`s;

- A `<span>` is an **inline** element
- A `<h1>` is a **block** element
- An **inline** element **cannot** contain a **block** element

Since the `<span>` is an [**inline** element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089953/can-you-have-a-span-within-a-span), it may contain another `<span>`.

However, to create a clean DOM, using the `<h1>` for the Google Bot, you should consider changing the DOM to:

```html
<div class="container">
   <span class="icon"></span>
   <div class="page-title">
      <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what if I style the h1 as inline instead of block. Does that work ? Any issue with that ?

Comment: @paulalexandru some browsers will render that part of code strangely if you put a h1 in a span tag.

Comment: Styling a component won't change the type or the kind of child's that are allowed.. It's still bad practice.

Comment: @Huangism Most browsers will display it even tho the DOM has invalid child elements.

Comment: I understand. Well if I use div instead of span, it means that I also have to style that div as inline or table-cell as the span right ? In order not to break the design.

Comment: You could write some CSS to let the `<div>` show as a `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why all the tags are span tags, and would strongly encourage refactoring this code so that it contains semantic tags. While Omiod is correct that the site won't break, it also won't be very accessible. Using semantic tags creates a clear information hierarchy.

At the very least I would (as @gilbert-v suggests) put a h1 tag in place of the title span. Taking it a step further I would suggest the following:

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use CSS to style it the way you need it to look.

Comment: This is a component used in thousands of places in the site. I would try to affect it as less as possible.

Answer (score 0):

All those elements aside from the icon should just be divs. I only use spans for wrapping text content, generally speaking.

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```