# Increase size of Icon in HTML

Tags: html

Is there a way to increase the size of icon below.I tried with size attribute but not working

```
<span style="color:red">&#x1F6C8</span>
```

Comment: well, it's actually a text, therefore you can use `font-size` attribute.

Comment: i know :) sorry ````<span style="color:red">sdsd &#x1F6C8</span>```` I want to increase only the icon size here :)

Answer (score 2):

well, as mentioned in comment, it's actually a text, therefore you can use CSS `font-size` attribute to increase the size of icon. Also, you missed a `;`.

```html
<span style="color:red; font-size: 80px">&#x1F6C8;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **font-size** will work, try put it in style

Comment: This is a working answer but I think It has really small content and info for actually helping, unlike the answer of @Raptor

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to increase the size of the icon then you can wrap it in another `span` element and set a bigger `font-size` for this element only :

```css
.icon {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span style="color:red">sdsd <span class="icon">&#x1F6C8;</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to nest a span like this:

```
<span style="color:red">sdsd <span style="font-size:36px">&#x1F6C8</span></span>
```

Nesting spans is valid, see this question:

[Can you have a <span> within a <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089953/can-you-have-a-span-within-a-span)