# How do I activate a YUI Datepicker only by a seperate Icon, not by the referenced input field?

Tags: javascript, yui, liferay-aui

I want to display a AUI / YUI [DatePicker](http://alloyui.com/api/modules/aui-datepicker.html) ([Tutorial](http://alloyui.com/tutorials/datepicker/)) that **only** gets activated by a click on a corresponding icon, **not** on `focus` or `click` events as normal.

```js
var AUI = YUI;
AUI().use('event', 'aui-datepicker', function(A) {
function createCalendar(calendarInputBox) {
var datumInputField = calendarInputBox.one('input.calendar');
var datumInputFieldSelector = '#' + datumInputField.get('id').replace(/:/g, '\\:');
var datepickerIcon = calendarInputBox.one('.calendarInputIcon');

var datepicker = new A.DatePicker({
    container : datumInputFieldSelector,
    mask : '%d.%m.%Y',
    calendar : {
  firstDayOfWeek : 1,
    },
    popover : {
  zIndex : 1,
    }
});

function updateDatepickerFromInputAndShowDatepicker() {
    datumInputField.focus();
    datepicker.show();
}

datepickerIcon.on('click', updateDatepickerFromInputAndShowDatepicker);
}

A.all('.calendarInputBox').each(createCalendar);
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/2.0.0/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<span class="calendarInputBox" id="generated-0">
  <span class="calendarInputIcon">icon</span>
  <input id="generated-1" name="generated-2:form:from" type="text" value="" maxlength="10" class="calendar calendarFrom" />
</span>
```

I tried to use

- the icon as the container and read and write the date manually and the popup didn't appear any more
- `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` for `focus` and `click` events on the input, but it didn't supress the calender to be shown

It doesn't seem to be possible to connect the Datepicker with the input but seperate the showing/hiding from the usage of the input. Any ideas?

This is all inside a JSF 2.1 Portlet in Liferay 6.2, if it matters, the input is build by:

```
<span class="calendarInputBox">
<div class="calendarInputIcon"></div>
    <h:inputText id="from" value="#{searchData.from}" maxlength="10" styleClass="calendar calendarFrom">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
    </h:inputText>
</span>
```

Comment: Some side notes: I don't believe that `AUI({ lang : 'de-DE' })` does anything when running in Liferay portal. I believe that `AUI` gets its localization settings from the portal, and it cannot be changed. If you did want to have a separate component with different localization, you could use a separate `YUI` sandbox instead. Also [you should not put a `div` inside a `span`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545884/can-span-tags-have-any-type-of-tags-inside-them).

Comment: Thanks, I removed lang and changed the icon to use a span.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, it sounds like you want the icon to be the `trigger` for the `DatePicker` and you want it to update the input. If so, the following code should do the trick:

```js
var AUI = YUI;

AUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(A) {

    var input = A.one('#input');
    var datePicker = new A.DatePicker({
        trigger: '#div',
        calendar: {
            on: {
                dateClick: function(event) {
                    input.set('value', A.Date.format(event.date,{format:datePicker.get('mask')}));
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<input id="input" /><div id="div" class="icon-calendar">Click Me to Pop Up Calendar</div>
```

Side note: if you wanted the input to update the the `DatePicker` you could probably do something like what I'm doing in my [`initDatePickerShowOnButton` method](https://github.com/stiemannkj1/liferay-faces/blob/master/alloy/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/liferay-faces-alloy/alloy.js#L367).

Also, the end result of this code looks very similar to the Liferay Faces Alloy [`<alloy:inputDate showOn="button" />`](http://www.liferayfaces.org/web/guest/showcase/-/component/alloy/inputdate/general) component (which uses the AlloyUI `DatePicker`). So you may want to check that out and see if we've already solved your problem in a more JSF-ish way.

**Full Disclosure:** I am part of the Liferay Faces team, and I personnally wrote `alloy:inputDate`.