# AUI datepicker: How to access current element

Tags: javascript, datepicker, alloy-ui

Does anyone know the AUI datepicker?
There is a tutorial
http://alloyui.com/versions/2.0.x/examples/datepicker/
where this code is given:

```
YUI().use(
  'aui-datepicker',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.DatePicker(
      {
        trigger: 'button',
        popover: {
          zIndex: 1
        },
        on: {
          selectionChange: function(event) {
            console.log(event.newSelection)
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
);
```

My question is how to access the element the datepicker is assigned to, i. e. the button, in the callback selectionChange?
I tried to read the complete documentation but I didn't understand it.

Comment: What do you mean by accessing? Like for example `document.querySelector('button')`?

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the trigger element during the `selectionChange` event, you can do the following:

```
selectionChange: function(event) {
    var triggerNode = Y.one(event.target.get('trigger'));
    // Your code here ...
}
```

Here's a runnable example using your code that displays the html of the button on `selectionChange`:

```js
YUI().use('aui-datepicker', function(Y) {
  new Y.DatePicker({
    trigger: 'button',
    popover: {
      zIndex: 1
    },
    on: {
      selectionChange: function(event) {
        var triggerNode = Y.one(event.target.get('trigger'));
        alert(triggerNode.get('outerHTML'));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-calendar icon-white"></i> Select the date</button>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! Fairly complicated, no chance to get the answer on my own.

Comment: @UlrichBangert, Great! If this answers your question, then could you check the green mark next to the answer?

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Could easily get attributes of that element. One question remains: How can I get the date string being input into the input element (formatted according "mask")?

Comment: @UlrichBangert This Q&A should answer that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153115/how-do-i-activate-a-yui-datepicker-only-by-a-seperate-icon-not-by-the-reference/27159395#27159395

Comment: Thanks for this link. I seems to meet my question but I can' get it to work:

Comment: Thanks for this link. It seems to meet my question but I can' get it to work:
Unfortunately on dateClick doesn't trigger for me.
When I use on selectionChange target.date is undefined.
This is my complete code:
http://ulrichbangert.de/div/webdesign/javascript/form_dynamic_2.html

Comment: Moved one step forward but didn't reach the destination yet: on dateClick triggers now but unfortunately event.target.get('mask') and event.target.get('trigger') both return undefined.
In on  selectionChange both worked fine.
ulrichbangert.de/div/webdesign/javascript/form_dynamic_2.html

Comment: @UlrichBangert Sorry I made a bad edit to the question that I mentioned (I've since rolled it back). To do what you want, you can use either the `selectionChange` event or the `dateClick` event (but not both). Here's how to do it with `selectionChange`:
`selectionChange: function(event) {
/* you should probably check if newSelection has any values first */
Y.one('#input').set('value', Y.Date.format(event.newSelection[0],{format:event.target.get('mask')}));
}`

That will set this `<input id="input" type="text" />`'s value to the selected value.

Comment: If you need to use the `dateClick` event, then define the `datePicker` (`var datePicker = new DatePicker({ //...`). And change `event.target` to `datePicker` in the above code.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed instruction. I got it working now, but there were additional difficulties:
I was using a trigger selector resulting in a set of elements: `trigger:'input'`. When doing so the procedure you gave me always returns the first element of the matching set.
I fixed this by using a unique selector `trigger: "#input-" + dataName + i` resulting in e. g. '#inputchild0'.
I assume that there is no way to get the element currently operated.
However you answers helped me a lot and I say many many thanks again.

Comment: @UlrichBangert, great! Please give my answer a checkmark since it answered your original question.

Answer (score 0):

In your linked example, there is no "destination" the selected date is stored to.
You need an input field and change its value in the `selectionChange` function of your datepicker.

**HTML**

```
<input id="selected_date" class="field-input field-input-text" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-calendar icon-white"></i> Select the date</button>
```

**JS**

```
[...]
  on: {
    selectionChange: function(event) {
      document.getElementById("selected_date").value = event.newSelection;
    }
  }
[...]
```

---

BTW: If your developing for newer browsers, you could use `type="date"` for the input field, so you wouldn't need an external datepicker library.

Comment: If things would be that easy I would have found the solution on my own. But there are several input fields and I have to determine that one the datepicker is assigned to or the user has currently operated. (Reason: I have to store the selected date in the local storage.) Should be possible to derive it from this or event.The reason why we don't use the type="date" is insufficient browser support.

Comment: What do you mean with "assigned to"? In OnSelectionChange you define which input field get's edited by the datepicker. You can use data attributes to kind of show in the dom, that elemets are belonging together (like `data-belong-to="selected-date"` on the datepicker button). And if you make your input readonly (`readonly="readonly") and trigger the datepicker on click on the input field, the user can only manipulate the input field with the datepicker.