# How to align image and texts inside a span tag

Tags: css, css-position

I have this structure:

```
<span>
      <img src="images/logo.png" />
      <small>Title<small>
      <small>some text</small>
</span>
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
-------------------------
      -
  img -    Title
      - -----------------
      -    some text
-------------------------
```

Comment: Float, flexbox, absolute position comes to mind. Research those to learn a thing or two, or wait for a solution to copy and paste.

Comment: Your design has text that is not inline, so you may consider using `<div>` instead of `<span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span>
<div style="float: left;"><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>
<small>Title</small><BR>------------------<BR>
<small>some text</small>
</span>
```

Comment: You should not use `<div>` within a `<span>`; see more here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545884/can-span-tags-have-any-type-of-tags-inside-them

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS to make the span positioned absolutely, then you can also use absolute positioning with the image and two texts. For example:

```
Span {
  position: absolute;
  Left: x;
  Top: x;
  Right: auto;
  Bottom: auto;
}
Image {
  Position: absolute;
  Left: 0px;
  Top: 0px;
}
TextOne {
  position: absolute;
  Left: x;
  Top: 0px;
  Right: 0px;
  Bottom: X;
}
TextTwo {
  position: absolute;
  Left: X;
  Top: X;
  Right: 0px;
  Bottom: 0px;
}
```

Keep in mind, when positioning something absolutely inside another element, it positions based off of the parent element, not the entire screen. And sorry my post is formatted all weird, I'm doing this from a phone.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're looking for.
You can add some padding to text to make it look a little nicer.

```css
span img {
  float: left;
}
span small {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span>
      <img src="images/logo.png"/>
      <small>Title<small>
      <small>some text</small>
</span>
```