# Why is it causing an error when i put a <p> inside of a <span>?

Tags: html, font-awesome

I works properly but putting the code through a validator (validator.w3.org) comes up with an error

> Error: Element p not allowed as child of element span in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

```
<!-- mobile button -->
<a class="btn btn-warning lg hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"  role="button" href="http://www.website.com">
    <span>
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-pull-left black" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="black">Visit Store</p>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

See this stack overflow post: [Can <span> tags have any type of tags inside them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545884/can-span-tags-have-any-type-of-tags-inside-them)

Essentially, because `span` tags are inline elements, they should only contain other inline elements, not block elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was not searching 'inline elements' term. I adjusted my code and just got rid of the span and p elements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to include a 'block' element inside of an 'inline' element. That `<p>` tag should likely by a span or another inline element.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as the error says, `<p>` is not a valid child of `<span>`. `<p>` is a **block** level element, and `<span>` is an **inline** element. You can't have a block element within an inline element.

Either invert your two tags, or use a `<span>` within a `<span>`.

For further information, I recommend checking out the [**WhatWG documentation**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-span-element), which states that `<span>` tags should only be used when expecting **[phrasing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2)** content.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it causing an error when I put a <'p'> inside of a <'span'>?

**Side note:** --> I had to put quotes around the `paragraph` tag above otherwise, it would create a line break. same applies to `span` tag but that would result in different behaviour.

**Reasoning to the error:**

Only inline elements may be contained within inline elements. `span` is an inline element. tags such as `<p>`  which is block element cannot go inside inline elements.

**What does this error mean?**

There are rules regarding which `elements` can be nested inside other `elements` and when this is allowed to happen.

Most notably, block-level elements, such as `<div>`, are not allowed inside inline elements such as `<span>`.

This error is telling you that your markup includes a `<p>` element inside a `<span>` and that this is not allowed.

Here is a [LINK](http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/element-x-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-y-in-this-context-suppressing-further-errors-from-this-subtree/element-p-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-span-in-this-context-suppressing-further-errors-from-this-subtree/) that explains exactly what you have asked about the W3C validator error.