# Change color for child span on hovering

Tags: css

I have the following html code :

```
<ul>
   <li id="ajson1" class="node">
      <a href="#" id="ajson1_anchor">Afrique</a>
      <span class="action-button-container">
               <span class="icon">X</span>
               <span class="icon">Y</span>
               <span class="icon">Z</span>
            </span>
      <ul>
         <li id="ajson2" class="node">
            <a href="#" id="ajson2_anchor">Maroc</a>
            <span class="action-button-container">
               <span class="icon">X</span>
               <span class="icon">Y</span>
               <span class="icon">Z</span>
            </span>
         </li>
         <li id="ajson3" class="node">
            <a href="#" id="ajson3_anchor">Algerie</a>
            <span class="action-button-container">
               <span class="icon">X</span>
               <span class="icon">Y</span>
               <span class="icon">Z</span>
            </span>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

So what I want to do is to set all spans with the class `icon` inside the span `action-button-container` to `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`.
And then when I hover on the `li` element with the class `node` to set `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);` to spans with the class `icon` inside the first `.action-button-container` child.
And then when I hove on rhe spans with the class `icon` i want to set `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);`.

here is a demo for what I tried, but it didn't work as expected :

DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/pw9ryrnp/

Comment: QUOTE "According to the HTML Living Standard, the content model for SPAN elements is "Phrasing content"." [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545884/can-span-tags-have-any-type-of-tags-inside-them)

Answer (score 2):

This was a broken selector:

```
.node:hover .action-button-container:first-child .icon {
```

This is what it should be to accomplish what you want:

```
.node:hover > .action-button-container:first-of-type .icon {
```

Why it works:

1. The `>` selector (child combinator) makes sure that the rule will only apply to `.action-button-container` elements that are direct children of the `.node` being hovered (not grandchildren.
2. You were using `:first-child` incorrectly, as that selector will choose the first child element of a parent regardless of whether it matches your class selector. It couldn't find any `.action-button-container` that was the first child of a parent, so it never triggered. Instead, we can use `:first-of-type`, since those elements are the first `span` in each `.node`.

EDIT: Made more changes to fix caveat.

```css
.action-button-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.node .action-button-container .icon {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.node > a:hover + .action-button-container:first-of-type .icon,
.node > .action-button-container:hover .icon {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.node > .action-button-container:first-of-type .icon:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="ajson1" class="node">
        <a href="#" id="ajson1_anchor">Afrique</a>
        <span class="action-button-container">
          <span class="icon">X</span>
          <span class="icon">Y</span>
          <span class="icon">Z</span>
        </span>
        <ul>
            <li id="ajson2" class="node">
                <a href="#" id="ajson2_anchor">Maroc</a>
                <span class="action-button-container">
                  <span class="icon">X</span>
                  <span class="icon">Y</span>
                  <span class="icon">Z</span>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li id="ajson3" class="node">
                <a href="#" id="ajson3_anchor">Algerie</a>
                <span class="action-button-container">
                  <span class="icon">X</span>
                  <span class="icon">Y</span>
                  <span class="icon">Z</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I hover a child `li` the parent get hovered too, and when I hover `span.icon` it does nothing.

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU Fixed both of those issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `>` child css selector to only select the child of the element being hovered.

Below I have changed `.node:hover .action-button-container:first-child .icon` to `.node:hover>.action-button-container .icon`

```css
.action-button-container{
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.node .action-button-container .icon{
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.node:hover>.action-button-container .icon {
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.node .action-button-container .icon:hover{
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li id="ajson1" class="node">
      <a href="#" id="ajson1_anchor">Afrique</a>
      <span class="action-button-container">
               <span class="icon">X</span>
               <span class="icon">Y</span>
               <span class="icon">Z</span>
            </span>
      <ul>
         <li id="ajson2" class="node">
            <a href="#" id="ajson2_anchor">Maroc</a>
            <span class="action-button-container">
               <span class="icon">X</span>
               <span class="icon">Y</span>
               <span class="icon">Z</span>
            </span>
         </li>
         <li id="ajson3" class="node">
            <a href="#" id="ajson3_anchor">Algerie</a>
            <span class="action-button-container">
               <span class="icon">X</span>
               <span class="icon">Y</span>
               <span class="icon">Z</span>
            </span>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
#ajson1 .icon:hover{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#ajson2 .icon:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#ajson3 .icon:hover{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

I was updating your js fiddle.
Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pw9ryrnp/
Maybe this is can help you