# Expanding child (in small parent element) element on hover (depending on elements quantity)

Tags: jquery, css

I have table where there are small elements (about 20px) with number (how many times something was used). On hover there is displayed child element (position absolute) which contains places where it was used. So there are links and it may be even few hundred px width. HTML looks like that:

```css
.el-used {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #d7d6d5;
  font-size: 0.938em;
}

.el-used:hover {
  background: #ff6840;
  color: #fff;
}

.el-used .list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0.9em;
  display: none;
  width: 20em;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
  border: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
}

.el-used:hover .list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.el-used .list a {
  margin-right: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="el-used">1<span class="list">Wszystkie</span></span>
</div>
<div><span class="el-used">1<span class="list"><a href="/1">O firmie</a></span></span>
</div>
<div><span class="el-used">6<span class="list"><a href="/">O firmie</a> <a href="/4">Oferta</a> <a href="/5">Podstrona 1</a> <a href="/6">Podstrona 2</a> <a href="/8">Podstrona 4</a> <a href="/2">Mapa strony</a></span></span>
</div>
```

Problem is that I must set that **width:20em;** if I don't want every link element to be in separate row. Because as I assume that .list element is trying to fit in parent (.el-used) so it has small width and text is wraped.
I would like to set (instead of that width) only e.g. max-width:20em and it will shrink if there is only one element and grow (up to these 20em) when there are more elements.

Some suggestions how I can solve it?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Can you perhaps provide an image?

Comment: Yes, I want this to be wide as it is (so e.g. max-width:20em): https://imgur.com/a/eEaSv but this https://imgur.com/a/CzMDj to be only as wide as one link need space (so I need to remove width:20em).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that I refactored your HTML quite a bit:

- things that *are* a list should be marked-up as such, hence the `<ul>`
- take care when nesting elements: a [`div` should not reside within a `span`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545884/can-span-tags-have-any-type-of-tags-inside-them)
- beware of elements' default `display`-property: `span`s are `inline`, whereas `div`s are `block`; understanding this will allow you to leverage the full power of CSS: inline follows text flow, whereas block causes breaks and can have padding/margin

**Edit**

Since you mentioned you want your markup to reside in a table, I edited my original answer to account for this. Basically, setting the list items to `white-space: nowrap;` prevents them from linebreaking internally.

I also added a class `.wide` which manually specifies how wide boxes with several elements should be. You have to set this width manually; at least I couldn't think of a solution without fixed widths. Below are two examples: `(6)` has `.wide` and the list items spread out, `(12)` does not have `.wide` and hence they lign up below each other.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.el-used {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #d7d6d5;
  font-size: 0.938em;
}

.el-used:hover {
  background: #ff6840;
  color: #fff;
}

.el-used .list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0.9em;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border: inherit;
  max-width: 20em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.el-used .list.wide {
  width: 15em;
}

.el-used:hover .list {
  display: block;
}

.el-used .list li {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="el-used">1
            <ul class="list">
              <li>Wszystkie</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>Fourth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="el-used">1
            <ul class="list">
              <li><a href="/1">O firmie</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>Fourth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="el-used">
            6
            <ul class="list wide">
              <li><a href="/">O firmie</a></li>
              <li><a href="/4">Oferta</a></li>
              <li><a href="/5">Podstrona 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="/6">Podstrona 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="/8">Podstrona 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="/2">Mapa strony</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>Fourth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="el-used">
            12
            <ul class="list">
              <li><a href="/">O firmie</a></li>
              <li><a href="/4">Oferta</a></li>
              <li><a href="/5">Podstrona 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="/6">Podstrona 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="/8">Podstrona 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="/2">Mapa strony</a></li>
              <li><a href="/">O firmie</a></li>
              <li><a href="/4">Oferta</a></li>
              <li><a href="/5">Podstrona 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="/6">Podstrona 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="/8">Podstrona 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="/2">Mapa strony</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>Fourth</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks it is a lot better but at the end I need to put it in table ceil, so it will shrink to that cail width: https://jsfiddle.net/483yrp3x/

Comment: @roiwew cool that you found a solution that works for you! However, you should only use ´table´s for actual tabular data. Using them for layouting purposes will sooner or later cause you headaches.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find a solution, because shrinking .list depending on table ceil is not what I need. I need it to be wider than ceil. You can check that jsfiddle link I posted before.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your comment. Will take a look!

Comment: Thanks but it looks the same to me as if it was set at start. Of course I can check in PHP if there are more elements and add a wide class. But I was looking for some strict CSS solution for that. But despite this thanks for your help.

Comment: @roiwew, you could, if it is available to you, use Javascript to count the elements in a container, and based on the result add your class. This should have no detrimental impact on your UX, since the container is hidden by default.