# How to reuse JSX elements in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I don't know separate the code in span and the text appending it

```
getAuthorInfo() {
    if (this.props.anonymous_author) {
        return <p className="meta-data-type topic-label">{this.props.author.display_name}, {this.props.author.primary_specialty_name}</p>;
    }
    return <p className="meta-data-type topic-label">{this.props.author.display_name}, {this.props.author.primary_specialty_name} <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" />{this.props.author.location}</p>;
}
```

I don't think jsx let me to define a variable to be just  and raw text
any ideas?

Comment: Can't really understand your question

Comment: Are you using React 16?

Answer (score 0):

```
getAuthorInfo() {
  return (<p className="meta-data-type topic-label">
      {this.props.author.display_name}, {this.props.author.primary_specialty_name}
      {!this.props.anonymous_author &&
        (<span className="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" />
        {this.props.author.location})}
    </p>);    
}
```

Comment: While this is better than the original it still suffers from being non-reusable across components

Comment: Its not reusable across, but at least without block duplication.

Comment: I can see the syntax error right from your post, don't even need to copy&paste to IDE....

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
getAuthorInfo() {
    let location;
    if (!this.props.anonymous_author) {
        location = (<span><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" />{this.props.author.location}</span>);
    }
    return <p className="meta-data-type topic-label">Top answer from {this.props.author.display_name}, {this.props.author.primary_specialty_name} {location} </p>;
}
```

The key point is I wrap the span+text with another span. And it's allowed in html, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5545914/5326788

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking about this the wrong way. You shouldn't be returning JSX from functions like this because it's not re-usable and runs into the problems which you are having right now.

All the other answers here are still not testable or re-usable across components.

I don't know how you render at the moment, but let's say you render it like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    getAuthorInfo() {
        if (this.props.anonymous_author) {
            return <p className="meta-data-type topic-label">{this.props.author.display_name}, {this.props.author.primary_specialty_name}</p>;
        }
        return <p className="meta-data-type topic-label">{this.props.author.display_name}, {this.props.author.primary_specialty_name} <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" />{this.props.author.location}</p>;
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.getAuthorInfo()}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Becomes this:

```
const MyComponent = () => <AuthorInfo />;

const AuthorInfo = (props) => (
  <p className="meta-data-type topic-label">
    {props.author.display_name}, {this.props.author.primary_specialty_name}

    {!props.anonymous_author ? <AnonymousAuthor author={props.author} /> : null}
  </p>
);

const AnonymousAuthor = (props) => (
  <div>
    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" />
    {props.author.location}
  </div>
);
```

You gain intellisense. It's re-usable and you can export each component to test easily in isolation. If you don't want to use ternary operators then you can use recompose [`branch()`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#branch) function but this is more advanced.

Comment: "All the other answers here are still not testable or re-usable across components." This is flatly not true, -1 for this claim

Comment: @WilliamB How would you reuse OP's `getAuthorInfo` in other components? They are testable actually apart from the string concat answer

Comment: Modularity & code reuse existed before React. Same way you would share any other logic, module, object, etc.

Comment: @WilliamB Sure. If you want to be pedantic, you could re-use it but it's not nice which is what I was trying to get across to OP. A big point of React is to split it out into different components for easy re-use. You have to then split that code out into a shared function which makes no sense.

Comment: But "Just because you can factor something out doesn’t mean that you must factor it out." It's incorrect to say methods that return JSX should always be separate components. There's a lot of rules of thumb in this area, and over-componentizing all of your render logic will actually be a poor dev experience IMO. https://reactarmory.com/answers/how-should-i-separate-components

Comment: how can you tell if this is reusable without knowing the other part of the code? It may look unreusable to you but I am actually reusing this component, and it works fine.

Comment: @MarshallX and when you want to re-use anonymous author or author info again in other components you will have to split it out like I did here into separate components. That's what I meant. You can't use pure stateless functions with methods on classes either.