# Text displays under image instead of inline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to say "my website bby" right next to the image logo and for some reason it displays under the logo. Help me please. Here is what it is right now, [check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeFDl.png)

Here is my `html`:

```css
body {
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Optima, sans-serif;
    line-height:1.5;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}

.container {
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}


header {
    font-family: Monaco, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    padding-top:100px;
    min-width: 90%;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#6BD326;
}

#logo {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.branding {
    float: left;
}

nav li {
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav {
    float:right;
}

#logo {
    margin-top:5px; 
    width:40%;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="branding">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" style="width:100px;" />
            </div>
                <span><h1><u>My</u>&nbsp;Website&nbsp;bby</h1></span>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Photogallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

To have a better understanding of what I'm talking about, check the picture above. I just started out coding, really need to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try with flex and delete `float:left`

```
.branding {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a combination of `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`.

For example:

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Optima, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}


header {
  font-family: Monaco, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 100px;
  min-width: 90%;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #6BD326;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.i-b {
  display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(100% - 40%);
}

.branding {
  float: left;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="branding">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/536/354.jpg?hmac=i0yVXW1ORpyCZpQ-CknuyV-jbtU7_x9EBQVhvT5aRr0" style="width:100px;" />
            </div>
                <span class="i-b"><h1><u>My</u>&nbsp;Website&nbsp;bby</h1></span>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Photogallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

[Jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/hz59exy0/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code which is work

body like that :

```
 <body>
<div class="branding">

    <div id="logo">
        <img src="./img/logo.png" style="width:100px;" />
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Photogallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
        <span><h1 style="padding: 30px; margin-left:130px;"><u>My</u>&nbsp;Website&nbsp;bby</h1></span>
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

your css should be like that :

```
body {
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Optima, sans-serif;
    line-height:1.5;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
.body img{
    display: inline;
}

.container {
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}


header {
    font-family: Monaco, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    padding-top:100px;
    min-width: 90%;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#6BD326;
}

#logo {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}



nav li {
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

your mistake was here

```
.branding {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the `<div class="branding">` you can add another `div` with a style:

`display: flex;`
`justify-content: space-between`

Answer (score 0):

Please run your code through the W3C Validator.

You will see that you have an error in the HTML:

*Error: Element h1 not allowed as child of element span in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)*

You can find out more about the distinction between block and inline elements at [Can <span> tags have any type of tags inside them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545884/can-span-tags-have-any-type-of-tags-inside-them) which in turn references the formal spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

For your immediate problem you could make the span a div (which can have h1 elements as children) and make both it and the image inline-blocks.

Answer (score -1):

check this out i removed all the floats and worked with flex

```css
body {
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Optima, sans-serif;
    line-height:1.5;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}

.container {
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}


header {
    font-family: Monaco, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    padding-top:100px;
    min-width: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#6BD326;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#logo {    
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#logo span{
  margin-left: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
}
nav li {
    padding: 0px 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header>        
<div class="branding">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/BVb3Wzn9orDR8mwVnhrSyd-1200-80.jpg" style="width:100px;" />
                <span><u>My</u>&nbsp;Website&nbsp;bby</span>
            </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Photogallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```