# Vertically align text in a span tag without specifying height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is a similar question and the answers either wrap another element or specify height:
[How do I vertically align something inside a span tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732337/how-do-i-vertically-align-something-inside-a-span-tag)

Is it possible to do this:

```html
        <span style="
                  background-color:linen;
                  font-size: 2rem; 
                  font-weight: 500; 
                  padding: 2rem;">
CENTER ME VERTICALLY
            </span>
```

And get `CENTER ME VERTICALLY` to do so without specifying height.  I can get this to work with flex box and element wrapping, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler more elegant way to do it?

Comment: to center vertically based on what? you text define the height of the span so it's already vertically aligned

Comment: default value is line-height: normal. You can change it. That's the only thing you can specify if you don't want to specify height.

Comment: I added background color.  Notice that the text is not aligned vertically.

Comment: I'm confused. If your display is set to inline-block, then why did you accept the answer that says to set it to inline-block?

Comment: See comment at top.

Comment: you don't add answer to the question. A question need to remain a question

Comment: also your issue isn't a centring issue but the fact that padding on inline element does't affect the layout. Add padding to the body element to notice this: https://jsfiddle.net/gq9s6wcm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will answer your question.

You are using `span` which display is inline.
try to add `display: inline-block` if you want to use `span`